# Closing InternalWindow

Tags: tornadofx

In my aplication I open an InternalWindow with menu/item. When the modal window should be closed with close() the whole application exits. It seems that this behavior is present since version 1.7.15. 
Greetings from Germany.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed a little while ago and is available in the SNAPSHOT releases. It will be in the 1.7.16 release shortly :)